# How can an SSL certificate error show only for non-www domain?

Tags: ssl, https

WhyNoPadlock (and SEMrush) are reporting that that the SSL certificate for [https://www.castilleresources.com] is OK but the SSL certificate for [https://castilleresources.com] (excluding www) is expired.

I reported it to the Web Dev company and they replied:
"This is not the correct domain that the site is hosted on so I do not believe the errors shown would be correct".

How can an SSL certificate be OK for [www] Domain but expired for [non-www] Domain?
This is the first time ever I come across such an issue.
Is the Web Dev company correct or is there something they should do to fix this?
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: "How can an SSL certificate be OK for [www] Domain but expired for [non-www] Domain? "  Why not? A  web server can be configured with different certificates for each name. The certificate served when browsing https://castilleresources.com is indeed expired since 1 year. You have to remove it or stop answering HTTPS queries on this name. Besides your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Apologies @PatrickMevzek, my first time here. (Thanks for the reply)